# Why I can't get the exact same color when exporting an image to jpg

Tags: colors, export, jpeg, photoshop

I have an Illustrator, a PNG image and an SVG file with a box filled with `#041C2C` color (a dark blue).
When I'm trying to export any of these files to jpg, the image result change a little bit the red value and alter the color to `#051c2c`.

I used Illustrator, Photoshop, Sketch and InVision Studio with **different export settings**. I also tried and [online jpg generator](https://onlinejpgtools.com/generate-random-jpg?color-picker=%23041c2c&colors=%23041c2c&size=20&width=300&height=300&shade=false&shade-threshold=0) but the downloaded image always shows the wrong color when I opened it back.
In Photoshop I play with color profiles but nothing good happens.

**Can any of you replicate what I did but obtaining the correct color?**

**Is there a method to get the original color?**

Comment: Yes, I get the same shift in color values - it's normal as JPEG uses  _"lossy"_ compression. As a result of the many steps your image passes through when saving as JPEG this color shift is inevitable. Those steps can include; color space conversion, chroma downsampling, encoding/compression. This [article](https://www.quora.com/How-many-colors-does-a-JPEG-contain) explains the process in further detail.

Comment: @RobC this is a new form of loss that I've never heard of before with JPEG, as given by one answer. I wouldn't call it "normal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a color cannot be stored in the JPEG format.

For the `#041c2c` color, the corresponding (R, G, B) values are (4, 28, 44).
For the `#051c2c` color, the corresponding (R, G, B) values are (5, 28, 44).

According to the [JFIF standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format), YCbCr colors (with 256 levels per component) can
be computed directly from full scale 8-bit per color channel RGB colors as follows:

```
Y  = Min(Max(0, Round(  0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B)), 255)                = Min(Max(0, Round(22.648)), 255)        = 23
Cb = Min(Max(0, Round((-0.299*R - 0.587*G + 0.886*B) / 1.772 + 128)), 255) = Min(Max(0, Round(140.0496614)), 255)   = 140
Cr = Min(Max(0, Round(( 0.701*R - 0.587*G - 0.114*B) / 1.402 + 128)), 255) = Min(Max(0, Round(114.699001427)), 255) = 115
```

So the (Y, Cb, Cr) triplet is (23, 140, 115).

The inverse relationship for computing full scale 8-bit per color channel RGB values from YCbCr colors
(with 256 levels per component) can be computed as follows:

```
R = Min(Max(0, Round(Y + 1.402 * (Cr - 128))), 255) = Min(Max(0, Round(4.774)), 255) = 5
G = Min(Max(0, Round(Y - (0.114 * 1.772 * (Cb - 128) + 0.299 * 1.402 * (Cr - 128)) / 0.587)), 255) = Min(Max(0, Round(28.1541362862)), 255) = 28
B = Min(Max(0, Round(Y + 1.772 * (Cb - 128))), 255) = Min(Max(0, Round(44.264)), 255) = 44
```

As you can see, the (R, G, B) values are (5, 28, 44).

**No combination of YCbCr values leads to the (4, 28, 44) on the output.**

Comment: This is a fascinating fact about JPEG that I never knew. I just verified it by filling a large block with (4,28,44) in Paint.net and saving it as a JPEG at the highest quality, and it comes back (5,28,44) just as you say.

Comment: The problem here is floating point arithmetic. And there are two sources of problem here. First, the values get rounded in both the RGB=>YCbCr and YCbCr=>RGB conversions. The second problem is rounding in the JFIF representation of the transform. These conversions are linear transforms and can be represented by matrices. JPEG version is rounded to three decimal points so it it can easily be off by about a half pixel value if yo were representing the values in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

You face several problems. One is the RBG color space used in PNG and the YCbCr colorspace used in JPEG do not have the same gamut. If you represent the RBG color space as a graph you get a cube of colors that can be represented. If you overlay the YCbCr color space you get another cube with a vertex at (0,0,0) but the cube is rotated.

When you do an RBG to YCbCr conversion, values outside the YCbCr box get clamped to fit inside the box.

Another is the JPEG process uses floating point arithmetic that results in rounding.

Another is the quantization. You can avoid this one by using all 1s in your quantization able (and get poor compression).